# Remove symbol code

Tags: jquery, text, replace, title, symbols

We have a title

```
<title>Text &#8211; text</title>
```

I want to change it with jquery

```
$('title').html($('title').html().replace('Text-text', ''));
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: I find that a little difficult to read. In any case, "it doesn't work" should probably be followed by what actually happens, where things are failing, etc.

Comment: take a look at [this w3c school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set2) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) to replace the contents:

```
$('title').text('Text-text');
```

`.html()` is overkill if there's no actual HTML inside there.

To only replace certain characters in the title, use a callback function:

```
$('title').text(function(i,str) {
    return str.replace('replace this','with this');
});
```

To replace special characters, you'll need to use their Unicode encoding, which I found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) by googling "unicode 8211":

```
$('title').text(function(i,str) {
    return str.replace('\u2013','-');
});
```